# Java : build and print a grid in console (NO GUI)

Tags: java, oop, grid

`import java.util.Arrays;

public class Board {
    /**
     * Attributes
     */

```
// Rows and Columns
private static final int rows = 10;
private static final int cols = 10;

private static final int numOfObstacles = 5;
private static final int numOfFuelUps = 4;
// 2-D Array for the game board and obstacles and
private int[][] gameBoard;





/**
 * Constructors
 */

/**
 * Initialing the game's main board (grid).
 */

public Board() {
    this.gameBoard = new int[rows][cols];
    for(int i = gameBoard.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.println();
        for(int j = 0; j < gameBoard.length; j++) {
            gameBoard[i][j] = i * rows + j + 1;
             System.out.print(gameBoard[i][j] + "\t");
        }
    }   
}
```

`

Okay so. As you see I have a constructor that builds my 10x10 board

I'm not gonna use GUI yet I just want it to work in the console.
My board has to be in reverse order, like I want the 1-10 row to be at the bottom and 91-100 at the top and the player should follow a different direction, like in 1-10 row which will be at the bottom the player has to move from left to right and from 11-20 the player has to move from right to left.

I decided to constantly update the board by using StringBuilder

My problem is: how am I gonna make code for what I just described?
1-10 and
21-30 and
41-50 and
61-70 and
81-90 follow a specific direction while all the other rows a different direction

**UPDATED :
Now I only have to reverse the odd rows**

EXTRA:
That is one thing and the other thing is instead of printing the number I want to print the Players Id (Player1 or Player2 = there are 2 players in the game) if the player stands on a specific number. Would that be a good idea or should I only print a message? What do you think?

Comment: What are you hoping for as an answer to your question? Do you want us to simply write all code for you (because that's not going to happen)? You should attempt to solve your problem. You could start by maybe creating your `Player` class, drawing your board for once, creating an update loop and so on... Noone is going to code your project for you. Ask about a specific problem and we might be able to help though.

Comment: Obviously, I have those already... this is not what I asked, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inform yourself about String.format and its functionalities. Example: You can specify the "width" of a string. I guess that's what you need:

```
System.out.print(String.format("%-5s%-5d|", "|", 7));
```

Explanation:
That will give you this output:

```
|     7     |
```

You need to use one percent sign per additional parameter (we have two: "|" and 7) and a specifier for the format of the string (here: %s for string -> "|" and %d for decimal -> 7). The -5 sets the number of spaces before that variable.
Additionally, if you want to update the 7 to an 8, you can call this:

```
System.out.print(String.format("\r%-5s%-5d|", "|", 8));
```

The "\r" is doing the job.

Comment: Thanks that's new info